# Using TaskDialogIndirect in Python

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I want to call Windows [TaskDialogIndirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect) function from Python.
It needs [TaskDialogConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taskdialogconfig) (it's pretty big) structure to be passed as a pointer.

Here is my ready to run example. It gives me "-2147024809" (The parameter is incorrect) and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Python 3.7.4 x32, Windows 7 x64

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import *

TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION = 8
TDCBF_OK_BUTTON = 1

class TaskDialogConfig(ctypes.Structure):
    class DUMMYUNIONNAME(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ('hMainIcon', HICON)
            , ('pszMainIcon', LPCWSTR)
        ]

    class DUMMYUNIONNAME2(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ('hFooterIcon', HICON)
            , ('sFooterIcon', LPCWSTR)
        ]

    class _TASKDIALOG_BUTTON(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('nButtonID', INT)
            , ('pszButtonText', LPCWSTR)
        ]

    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', UINT)
        , ('hwndParent', HWND)
        , ('hInstance', HINSTANCE)
        , ('dwFlags', UINT)
        , ('dwCommonButtons', UINT)
        , ('pszWindowTitle', LPCWSTR)
        , ('DUMMYUNIONNAME', DUMMYUNIONNAME)
        , ('pszMainInstruction', LPCWSTR)
        , ('pszContent', LPCWSTR)
        , ('cButtons', UINT)
        , ('pButtons', _TASKDIALOG_BUTTON)
        , ('nDefaultButton', INT)
        , ('cRadioButtons', UINT)
        , ('pRadioButtons', _TASKDIALOG_BUTTON)
        , ('nDefaultRadioButton', INT)
        , ('pszVerificationText', LPCWSTR)
        , ('pszExpandedInformation', LPCWSTR)
        , ('pszExpandedControlText', LPCWSTR)
        , ('pszCollapsedControlText', LPCWSTR)
        , ('DUMMYUNIONNAME2', DUMMYUNIONNAME2)
        , ('pszFooter', LPCWSTR)
        , ('pfCallBack', ctypes.POINTER(None))
        , ('lpCallbackData', LPLONG)
        , ('cxWidth', UINT)
    ]

    def __init__(s):
        s.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(s)

tdi = ctypes.WinDLL('comctl32.dll').TaskDialogIndirect
tdc = TaskDialogConfig()
tdc.hwndParent = None
tdc.hInstance = None
tdc.dwFlags = TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION
tdc.dwCommonButtons = TDCBF_OK_BUTTON
tdc.pszWindowTitle = ctypes.c_wchar_p('Title')
tdc.pszMainInstruction = ctypes.c_wchar_p('Main instruction')
tdc.pszContent = ctypes.c_wchar_p('Content')
print( tdi(ctypes.byref(tdc), None, None, None) )
```

Comment: Does the size of the structure in Python match the size of the structure a C compiler reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues.

- The CommCtrl.h header uses a 1-byte packing.  Add `_pack_ = 1` before `_fields_` definition in all structures.
- The two `_TASKDIALOG_BUTTON` fields should be type `ctypes.POINTER(_TASKDIALOG_BUTTON)`.

I tracked these down by using a C program to print the size of the structure and the offsets of a few fields and printed the same info in Python:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(TASKDIALOGCONFIG));
    printf("%zu\n",offsetof(TASKDIALOGCONFIG,pszWindowTitle));
    printf("%zu\n",offsetof(TASKDIALOGCONFIG,pszMainInstruction));
    printf("%zu\n",offsetof(TASKDIALOGCONFIG,pszFooter));
}
```

```
tdc = TaskDialogConfig()
print(tdc.cbSize)
print(TaskDialogConfig.pszWindowTitle)
print(TaskDialogConfig.pszMainInstruction)
print(TaskDialogConfig.pszFooter)
```

Comment: This function is 15 years old and now we finally get a Python wrapper for it thanks to you!